# django creating generic class to validate User authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, generics, constructor

I am trying to replace the generic View class with a custom class so that the user authentication happens automatically when i make a reference to this class.

The Base Class

```
class CustomView(View):

    def __init__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            redirect('register.registerForm')
```

The sub class

class DashboardPage(CustomView):

```
def get(self, request):
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    all_files = user_object.files_set.all()
    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', {'all_files': all_files})
```

I expected the user authentication happened automatically when the CustomView class is called. And also wanted to know if this is the best way to generalize user authentication for all the pages in my application which require authentication.

I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError at /dashboard/
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\base.py in view, line 62
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Varun\\Desktop\\newsite',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2017.3-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Mon, 4 Dec 2017 20:43:12 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`LoginRequired` mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

If a user is not logged in, it will automatically redirect to the contents of the form field `redirect_to`. In the [default login form view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) this field is called `next`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not override `__init__` in a view class.

However, there is no need to do any of this. Django already includes a [LoginRequired mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) which does exactly what you want.